# Error parsing Kotlin source to AST with Kastree in IntelliJ

Tags: parsing, kotlin

I'm struggling a bizarr parse error when running Kastree Parser to build an AST from this example code written in Kotlin:

```
fun bar() {
    val a = "constant"
    val b = 0

    while (b < 10) {
        if (b < 5) {
            println("b lt 5")
        } else {
            println("b gt 5")
        }
    }

    if (true)
        return

    if (false) {
        return
    }

    println(a)

}
```

I use this `main` to parse program above:

```
import kastree.ast.psi.Parser
import java.io.File
import java.time.LocalDateTime

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val fileName = "C:/Users/LETS_GO_ON/Documents/kotcfg/KotlinCFG/src/test/kotlin/kotlincfg/Test11.kt"
    val file = File(fileName)
    if (!file.exists()){
        println("File does not exist")
        return
    }    

    val codeStr = file.readText()        
    val fileAst = Parser.parseFile(codeStr)
    val builder = GraphBuilder(fileAst)
    val graph = builder.build()
    val dotName = "dot.dot"
    val imgName = "graph-${LocalDateTime.now()}.png"
    exportToDot(graph, dotName)
    dotFileToImage(dotName, imgName)
}
```

Once it starts, an error message gets printed:

```
Exception in thread "main" ParseError(file=KtFile: temp.kt, errors=[PsiErrorElement:Expecting a top level declaration, PsiErrorElement:Expecting a top level declaration, PsiErrorElement:Expecting an element, PsiErrorElement:Expecting an expression, PsiErrorElement:Expecting '->', PsiErrorElement:Expecting an expression, is-condition or in-condition, PsiErrorElement:Expecting an expression, PsiErrorElement:Expecting '->', PsiErrorElement:Expecting an expression, is-condition or in-condition, PsiErrorElement:Expecting an expression, PsiErrorElement:Expecting '->', PsiErrorElement:Expecting an element, PsiErrorElement:Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line), PsiErrorElement:Expecting an element, PsiErrorElement:Expecting an element, PsiErrorElement:Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line), PsiErrorElement:Expecting an element])
    at kastree.ast.psi.Parser.parseFile(Parser.kt:25)
    at kastree.ast.psi.Parser.parseFile$default(Parser.kt:23)
    at main.kotlin.kotlincfg.MainKt.main(Main.kt:20)
```

Kastree dependency in `maven` project:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cretz.kastree</groupId>
            <artifactId>kastree-ast-psi</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

OS is Windows 10 Home, I apply JDK 1.8.0_271 to run a maven project in IntelliJ.
So, I wonder if somebody would explain what is wrong here in such a (seemingly) simple case for parsing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, that this parser doesn't know about `CRLF` [newline format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Workaround to handle this is simple - replace `CRLF` with `LF`:

```kotlin
val codeStr = file.readText().replace("\r\n", "\n")
```

Comment: Indeed, such a routine error every time switching to Windows (this code always worked on Ubuntu machine), but that's also very embarrassing for a hardcoding fresher like I'm. Surely, your answer is fine, thank you.